# When depth of a goal node is known, Which graph search algorithm is best to use BFS or DFS?

Tags: search, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

In a graph, when we know the depth at which goal node is, Which graph search algorithm is fastest to use: BFS or DFS?

Comment: In this case, you can use depth-limited search (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-limited_search) instead of DFS. But as alfasin mentioned, you need to precise your criteria : time? memory? solution optimality? completeness?

Comment: Thanks Vincent! i edited my question mentioning the criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And how would you define "best" ?

If you know that the goal node is at depth `n` from the root node (the node from which you begin the search), BFS - will ensure that the search won't iterate nodes with `depth > n`.

That said, DFS might still "choose" such a route that will be faster (iterate less nodes) than BFS.

So to sum up, I don't think that you can define "best" in such a scenario.

Comment: Thanks alfasin for your answer. I was looking for fastest algorithm. i'll edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, if the solution is at a known depth d, you can use [depth-limited search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-limited_search) instead of DFS. For all three methods (BFS, DFS and DLS), the algorithmic complexity is linear in the number of nodes and links in your state space graph, in the worst case (i.e. O(|V|+|E|).

In practice, depending on d, DLS can be faster though, because BFS requires developping the search tree until depth d-1, and possibly a part of depth d (so almost the whole tree). With DLS, this happens only in the worst cases.